# Building a list of objects from a list of parameters used to create them in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

What I want to accomplish looks like this (not in linq)

```
List<FileInfo> InfoList: ... //Already populated.
List<string> fileNames = new List<string>(InfoList.Count);
InfoList.ForEach(s => filesNames.Add(s.Name.ToString()));
```

The above code I've already written. I want to turn this next part into linq.

```
List<ZipArchiveEntry> ZipList = new List<ZipArchiveEntry>(InfoList.Count);

for(int i = 0; i < InfoList.Count; i++)
{
     ZipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(fileNames[i]);
     ZipList.Add(ZipArchiveEntry);
}
```

So basically, I want to know if you can use the elements of a list as parameters for a function to build a list of objects.

To make a zip archive entry, I need to call the method archive.CreateEntry(filename), and the file names are the elements of a list I've already built.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a normal projection, so [`Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) is your method:

```
var ZipList = fileNames.Select(archive.CreateEntry).ToList();
```

---

btw, your `fileNames` list can be easily created like that:

```
var fileNames = InfoList.Select(s => s.Name.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create `ZipList` directly from `InfoList`:

```
var ZipList = InfoList.Select(x => archive.CreateEntry(x.Name.ToString()))
                      .ToList();
```